# storeAttribute or storeElementPresent?

Tags: selenium, web, scripting, automation

I am hoping I can get some help, I need to know how to accomplish something but not sure how as I am new to selenium commands.

I tried the following:

```
storeEval
   javascript{window.document.getElementById('myDiv');}
   myResult

then 
gotoIf
  ${myResult} == false
  lblWhereToGoIfStyleDisplayIsNotVisible
```

This does not give me what I want as I always have the div in my page, even if the `style = display : none`.

What I need is to get the display property of the style of the div and check that value to see if none to then jump to the `lblWhereToGoIfStyleDisplayIsNotVisible` label

I was thinking I need to use storeAttribute or storeElementPresent but not sure how to implement properly to get result needed.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got my script working on my own as I was getting no quick responses, I tried many other type of searches about the gotoIf, css attributes, etc... and found one link at

http://sysmagazine.com/posts/190358/

which helped alot...

here is the final code if someone is interested in knowing how to get a div, display property value, store it, compare it to == NONE (if div is hidden) and go to the next label (test location in the script) in order to continue testing (setting dropdown values)....

this allows me to set values only if the div exists and is visible meaning the dropdown will have selections

This allowed me also to define 1 script for multiple possible test cases, just by changing the url based on the test I want to have.

Cheers!

---

```
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>window.getComputedStyle(window.document.getElementById('trProtection'),null).getPropertyValue('display');</td>
    <td>myResult</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['myResult'];}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>storedVars['myResult'] == &quot;none&quot;</td>
    <td>lblDivision</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>id=selProtection</td>
    <td>label=DISABILITY</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>lblDivision</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```